# How to play streamed URL link to mediaPlayer?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, audio-streaming

**mediaPlayer** won't play streamed radio link

my main goal is to make it so my android app can play a radio url link from [radio-browser.info](https://www.radio-browser.info/).
Most of the answers i find are just using a regular .mp3 link, not a streamed audio. On top of that, i believe most answers i find are outdated so the code doesn't quite work.

This is what i have:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var testingButton : Button
    var mediaPlayer : MediaPlayer? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        testingButton = findViewById(R.id.testingButton)

        testingButton.setOnClickListener{
            playAudio()
        }
    }

    private fun playAudio() {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        try {
            mediaPlayer!!.setDataSource("http://play.sas-media.ru/play_256")
            mediaPlayer!!.prepareAsync()
            mediaPlayer!!.start()
        }catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        Toast.makeText(this,"Audio started playing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

The app doesn't crash upon button press, it says "Audio Started playing" but actually plays nothing.
I feel like i'm missing something.

Edit:
Logcat errors upon button press:
MediaPlayerNative error (1, -2147483648)
MediaPlayer error (1, -2147483648)

and if i press the button again after that error

MediaPlayer error (-38,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the below code in your playAudio() method

```
mediaPlayer!!.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
```

setAudioStreamType is deprecated updated code-

```
    private fun playAudio() {
    val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
        .build()
    GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        try {
            val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource("https://play.sas-media.ru/play_256")
                mediaPlayer.setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                mediaPlayer.prepare()
            }
            mediaPlayer.start()
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Audio started playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Failed to play audio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
}
```